# Why can't I use my "back" button to go back from Stack Overflow to Google?

Tags: support, navigation

When I Google, and end up on Stack Overflow from it, if I click the back button to go back to Google, it just refreshes the page. I have to hold in the back button (in Chrome) and go down to the Google search history link to actually go back.

Is anybody else experiencing this? How can I make it stop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's Google's tracking redirect or (less likely) a redirect from an old URL to a new one. In general I don't think SO does anything that could cause this. What URL(s) are/were your visiting when this occurred?

Comment: Click twice, fast, but not too fast.

Comment: For example, go to google.com search for "php getdate vs date" click the SO link that appears. If I click the back button, it just refreshes the SO page.

Comment: To know when you click twice too fast, count the number of photons: If you see just a photon, you clicked  twice too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my Google Chrome from version 15.0.874.121 to version 16.0.912.63 m and it doesn't seem to be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 4):

> For example, go to google.com search for "php getdate vs date" click
>   the SO link that appears. If I click the back button, it just
>   refreshes the SO page. – Catfish 8 mins ago

I am unable to reproduce this in any way, shape, or form. Chrome v 16.0.912.63 on Mac OS X 10.7.2

What is the URL Google is sending you to? Is it a Google tracking URL? If it's a StackOverflow URL, is the slug correct? Does this happen all the time or only for certain search results?

[image: Google FHC]

Comment: I'm on Chrome version 15.0.874.121 m on Windows 7. I am seeing the exact same slug as you are. This happens all the time for SO pages from google.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's something Google is doing; not SO.  When I google, "jquery enable disable" I end up at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531747/jquery-enable-disable-text-box-based-on-radiobutton).

However, this is the link that gets loaded into my back button:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1531747%2Fjquery-enable-disable-text-box-based-on-radiobutton&ei=lhPqTsrqAYPg2QXv1qnLCA&usg=AFQjCNFQ0MlExHmar7QPQLBYdkhlyn9zWA

Edit: I should add that I'm using IE9.

Comment: So you have the same issue?